# Cannot upload the files into AWS S3 bucket with ACL pubic-read using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to upload the file into s3 bucket but I am getting access denied error when I am trying to upload the files with ACL public-read

It is working fine with ACL private

```
class S3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__s3_bucket = app.config['aws_bucket']
        self.__s3_client = boto3.client(
               "s3",
                aws_access_key_id=app.config['aws_access_key_id'],
                aws_secret_access_key=app.config['aws_secret_access_key']
        )

    def upload(self, file, filename='',  acl="public-read"):
        if len(filename) == 0:
            filename = file.filename

        self.__s3_client.put_object(
            file,
            self.__s3_bucket,
            filename,
            ACL=acl
        )
        return f'http://{self.__s3_bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{filename}'
```

Error:

```
An error occured (AccessDenied) when calling the putObject operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deactivate **Block S3 Public Access**.

If you wish to use ACLs, you will need to turn OFF these options:

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through *new* access control lists (ACLs)
- Bloack public access to buckets and objects granted through *any* access control lists (ACLs)

[image: Block S3 public access - ACLs]

Comment: I have these set correctly and can upload a file, but I still get the same error as above when adding the 'public-read' option. Any ideas?

Comment: @rleffler To set the ACL value, you require the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission.

Comment: Thanks John.  For anyone running into my issue, I had to setup an override.ts  file for Storage and add that permission with the others (read,write, delete, whichever of those you allow).